# Realms.SynchronizationContextEventLoop error in realm

Tags: xamarin, realm

when we are trying update realm db multiple times its throwing following error

```
NHANDLED EXCEPTION:
System.ObjectDisposedException: Safe handle has been closed
at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Object:wrapper_native_0xda0c96a0 (intptr)
at Realms.SynchronizationContextEventLoopSignal+EventLoop+<Post>c__AnonStorey0.<>m__0 (System.Object _) [0x00012] in <550621f4184f47c0bdfce087c391c293>:0 
at Android.App.SyncContext+<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<Post>b__0 () [0x00000] in <d855bac285f44dda8a0d8510b679b1e2>:0 
at Java.Lang.Thread+RunnableImplementor.Run () [0x00008] in <d855bac285f44dda8a0d8510b679b1e2>:0 
at Java.Lang.IRunnableInvoker.n_Run (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this) [0x00008] in <d855bac285f44dda8a0d8510b679b1e2>:0 
at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object:f9edc18f-c720-423d-8576-23c20d8f6a89 (intptr,intptr)
```

we have tried to keep our code inside try and catch but its still throwing runtime error and application gets crashed

Code , here `EventType` is a normal class ( not derived from RealmObject ) but `Response` class is a `RealmObject` and it has `opportunitiesList` declared as 
`public IList<Opportunity> opportunitiesList { get; }` and its derived from `RealmObject`

```
private  void updateGetData(EventType e)
{
    try 
    {
        Realm realm = Realm.GetInstance();
        realm.WriteAsync(tempRealm =>
        {
            if (Settings.IsSingleOpportunityUpdated == false)
            {
                tempRealm.Add(e.response, true);
            }
            else if (Settings.IsSingleOpportunityUpdated)
            {
                if (e.response != null &&  e.response.opportunitiesList.Count > 0)
                {
                    long opportunityId = e.response.opportunitiesList[0].opportunityId;
                    var opportunity = tempRealm.All<Opportunity>().FirstOrDefault(d => d.opportunityId == opportunityId);
                    e.response.opportunitiesList[0].isOpportunitySync = 0;
                    e.response.opportunitiesList[0].isSync = SyncStatus.SYNCED;
                    e.response.opportunitiesList[0].mOpportunityId = opportunity.mOpportunityId;
                    Debug.WriteLine("Opportunity Id after getOpportunity " + opportunity.opportunityId + " " + opportunityId + " " + e.response.opportunitiesList[0].isSync);

                    tempRealm.Add(e.response.opportunitiesList[0], true);
                }
                else
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("RealmDB opportunity response is empty " + Settings.IsSingleOpportunityUpdated);
                }
            }
        });
    }
    catch(Exception exception)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("RealmDB " + exception.StackTrace);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you try `await`-ing the `WriteAsync` call or using the synchronous version?

Comment: @NikolaIrinchev this is not working i tried that too its getting crash everytime

Comment: I'd suggest filing an issue on https://github.com/realm/realm-dotnet/issues as we'd need more info to further investigate and Stack Overflow is generally poorly suited for that.